# Compiling Flex Projects with Remote Ant

Tags: apache-flex, ant

I'm having problems compiling applications with remote ant, something similar to [this](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CC/RobertsRemoteAnt). However the flex compiler seems to have problems with this. When I run the same script on my local compiles everything without any problems but when I try the remote ant it fails without giving more information.

Answer (score 0):

Things to look for on the remote machine:

- The paths in the build file need to be valid (I'm pretty sure the script file you use to build the project on your computer, will not be good on the remote one because of a possible difference in paths)
- You need the Flex SDK installed
- You need Java JDK installed
- You might also need some environment variables set correctly (like JAVA_HOME)
- ANT binaries on the remote machine (but I assume you already have this, probably coming with the system you're using)
- The sources to be compiled, obviously (I assume you already have these too, probably gotten by your system from a repository)

Also I find it hard to believe it would fail without any error. There should be at least a log file somewhere to give you an idea of what went wrong.